# Problemas de loop de redirecionamento ao chamar página

Tags: c#

Fiz esse `if` e está dando loop de redirecionamento. Retirei o parâmetro `false` e continua. A página existe e etc...

```
if (Session["DsTipoUsuario"].ToString() == "1")
 {
     Response.Redirect("/frmGESStatusPriorizar.aspx", false);
 }
```

Antes dava esse erro e era a falta do parâmetro `false`. Agora dá pau com ele, mas somente nessa chamada.

Comment: Qual erro retorna?

Comment: Loop de redirecionamento, esse é o erro

Comment: Teste `Response.End();` depois do `Response.Redirect`!

Comment: Está dando esse erro ao dar um Response.End(): Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

Comment: Teoricamente o `Response.Redirect("pagina.aspx", false);` já encerraria a execução teste `Server.Transfer` ou `Server.Execute`. Tem um `try catch`no método?

Comment: O que tem na página páginafrmGESStatusPriorizar?

Comment: try..catch sim tem, pois tudo que faço eu coloco num try..catch. A página ela carrega uma lista de processos e o Gestor ele apenas prioriza processos para um analista determinado. Nada de especial. Vou colocar um break nela e posto o que está acontecendo e resolver posto também a resposta.